# GC Heap is huge but DumpHeap is small

Tags: memory, clr, heap-memory, windbg

I'm trying to analyze a dump file for high memory usage (the process reached 15GB) with windbg.

The application is very intensive and deals with high traffic, and we've dealt with memory issues in the past, but usually we figured out the issue with -DumpHeap stat which showed us the objects that were not released on time..

But this time, it's a different scenario. It seems that while -EEHeap shows that the GC Heap Size indeed goes over 14GBs, -DumpHeap stat doesn't show anything even close to that..
I've summed up all of the object in -DumpHeap stat (including the "Free" objects) and only reached 700MBs.

Based on the question asked here: ([WinDbg Address Summary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876516/windbg-address-summary)) I've also ran !address -summary which shows 14.8GB as unclassified but also MEM_COMMIT of 14.8GB, so it doesn't seem like the same scenario of a native leak.

Where can I go from here? Where are those missing 14GBs?

Thanks, and here are the outputs of !EEHeap and !address -summary

```
0:000> !EEHeap
Loader Heap:
--------------------------------------
System Domain: 000007feed372f20
LowFrequencyHeap: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
HighFrequencyHeap: 000007ff00022000(8000:8000) Size: 0x8000(32768)bytes.
StubHeap: 000007ff0002a000(2000:1000) Size: 0x1000(4096)bytes.
Virtual Call Stub Heap:
  IndcellHeap: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
  LookupHeap: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
  ResolveHeap: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
  DispatchHeap: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
  CacheEntryHeap: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Total size: 0x9000(36864)bytes
--------------------------------------
Shared Domain: ed373820
LowFrequencyHeap: 000007ff000e0000(2000:2000) 000007ff002d0000(10000:c000) Size: 0xe000(57344)bytes.
HighFrequencyHeap: 000007ff000e2000(8000:8000) 000007ff00910000(10000:10000) 000007ff00dc0000(10000:7000) Size: 0x1f000(126976)bytes.
StubHeap: 000007ff000ea000(2000:2000) 000007ff002c0000(10000:7000) Size: 0x9000(36864)bytes.
Virtual Call Stub Heap:
  IndcellHeap: 000007ff000f0000(5000:1000) Size: 0x1000(4096)bytes.
  LookupHeap: 000007ff000fa000(3000:1000) Size: 0x1000(4096)bytes.
  ResolveHeap: 000007ff00122000(3e000:3000) Size: 0x3000(12288)bytes.
  DispatchHeap: 000007ff000fd000(25000:1000) Size: 0x1000(4096)bytes.
  CacheEntryHeap: 000007ff000f5000(5000:1000) Size: 0x1000(4096)bytes.
Total size: 0x3c000(245760)bytes
--------------------------------------
Domain 1: 184070
LowFrequencyHeap: 000007ff00030000(2000:1000) 000007ff00160000(10000:10000) 000007ff00170000(10000:3000) 000007ff00180000(80000:80000) 000007ff00210000(10000:c000) 000007ff00220000(10000:10000) 000007ff00230000(10000:10000) 000007ff002a0000(10000:10000) 000007ff00320000(10000:1000) 000007ff00330000(30000:30000) 000007ff00370000(10000:e000) 000007ff003c0000(80000:80000) 000007ff00450000(10000:c000) 000007ff00460000(10000:10000) 000007ff00470000(10000:d000) 000007ff00480000(30000:2f000) 000007ff004b0000(10000:3000) 000007ff004c0000(20000:20000) 000007ff00530000(10000:10000) 000007ff00580000(10000:10000) 000007ff005d0000(10000:6000) 000007ff005f0000(40000:40000) 000007ff00630000(10000:5000) 000007ff00640000(30000:30000) 000007ff00670000(30000:30000) 000007ff006b0000(10000:10000) 000007ff006f0000(10000:10000) 000007ff00730000(10000:b000) 000007ff00760000(10000:f000) 000007ff00770000(10000:10000) 000007ff00790000(10000:10000) 000007ff007d0000(10000:10000) 000007ff00820000(10000:10000) 000007ff00850000(20000:1c000) 000007ff00880000(10000:10000) 000007ff008b0000(10000:10000) 000007ff008d0000(10000:10000) 000007ff00900000(10000:10000) 000007ff00930000(10000:10000) 000007ff00950000(10000:10000) 000007ff00990000(10000:e000) 000007ff009b0000(10000:10000) 000007ff00a10000(10000:f000) 000007ff00a30000(10000:10000) 000007ff00a70000(10000:10000) 000007ff00b00000(10000:10000) 000007ff00b40000(10000:10000) 000007ff00b70000(10000:10000) 000007ff00bc0000(10000:1000) 000007ff00bd0000(20000:20000) 000007ff00c30000(10000:10000) 000007ff00c70000(10000:e000) 000007ff00cf0000(10000:e000) 000007ff00d20000(10000:10000) 000007ff00d60000(10000:10000) 000007ff00dd0000(10000:c000) 000007ff00df0000(10000:10000) 000007ff00e10000(10000:10000) 000007ff00e70000(10000:10000) 000007ff00ea0000(10000:10000) 000007ff00ed0000(10000:10000) 000007ff00f30000(10000:5000) Size: 0x516000(5332992)bytes.
Wasted: 0x71000(462848)bytes.
HighFrequencyHeap: 000007ff00032000(8000:7000) 000007ff00200000(10000:10000) 000007ff00280000(10000:10000) 000007ff002b0000(10000:10000) 000007ff002e0000(10000:10000) 000007ff00360000(10000:10000) 000007ff003a0000(10000:f000) 000007ff00440000(10000:10000) 000007ff004e0000(10000:10000) 000007ff00500000(10000:10000) 000007ff00510000(10000:10000) 000007ff00520000(10000:10000) 000007ff00540000(10000:10000) 000007ff00560000(10000:10000) 000007ff00570000(10000:10000) 000007ff00590000(10000:10000) 000007ff005a0000(10000:10000) 000007ff005b0000(10000:10000) 000007ff005e0000(10000:10000) 000007ff006a0000(10000:10000) 000007ff006c0000(10000:10000) 000007ff006e0000(10000:10000) 000007ff00700000(10000:10000) 000007ff00710000(10000:10000) 000007ff00720000(10000:10000) 000007ff00750000(10000:10000) 000007ff00780000(10000:10000) 000007ff007a0000(10000:10000) 000007ff007c0000(10000:10000) 000007ff007e0000(10000:10000) 000007ff007f0000(10000:10000) 000007ff00810000(10000:10000) 000007ff00830000(10000:10000) 000007ff00840000(10000:10000) 000007ff00870000(10000:10000) 000007ff00890000(10000:10000) 000007ff008c0000(10000:10000) 000007ff008e0000(10000:10000) 000007ff008f0000(10000:10000) 000007ff00920000(10000:10000) 000007ff00940000(10000:10000) 000007ff00960000(10000:10000) 000007ff00970000(10000:10000) 000007ff009a0000(10000:10000) 000007ff009c0000(10000:10000) 000007ff009e0000(10000:10000) 000007ff00a00000(10000:10000) 000007ff00a20000(10000:10000) 000007ff00a40000(10000:10000) 000007ff00a60000(10000:10000) 000007ff00a80000(10000:10000) 000007ff00aa0000(10000:10000) 000007ff00af0000(10000:10000) 000007ff00b10000(10000:10000) 000007ff00b30000(10000:10000) 000007ff00b50000(10000:10000) 000007ff00b90000(10000:10000) 000007ff00bb0000(10000:10000) 000007ff00bf0000(10000:10000) 000007ff00c00000(10000:10000) 000007ff00c20000(10000:10000) 000007ff00c40000(10000:10000) 000007ff00c50000(10000:10000) 000007ff00cc0000(10000:10000) 000007ff00d00000(10000:10000) 000007ff00d30000(10000:10000) 000007ff00d50000(10000:10000) 000007ff00d80000(10000:10000) 000007ff00da0000(10000:10000) 000007ff00db0000(10000:10000) 000007ff00e20000(10000:10000) 000007ff00e80000(10000:10000) 000007ff00eb0000(10000:10000) 000007ff00ee0000(10000:10000) 000007ff00f40000(10000:1000) Size: 0x497000(4812800)bytes.
Wasted: 0x2000(8192)bytes.
StubHeap: 000007ff0003a000(2000:2000) 000007ff002f0000(10000:10000) 000007ff00300000(10000:10000) 000007ff00310000(10000:10000) 000007ff00390000(10000:10000) 000007ff009f0000(10000:10000) 000007ff00b80000(10000:10000) 000007ff00de0000(10000:d000) Size: 0x6f000(454656)bytes.
Virtual Call Stub Heap:
  IndcellHeap: 000007ff00040000(6000:6000) Size: 0x6000(24576)bytes.
  LookupHeap: 000007ff0004f000(4000:4000) 000007ff009d0000(10000:8000) Size: 0xc000(49152)bytes.
  ResolveHeap: 000007ff00084000(5c000:28000) Size: 0x28000(163840)bytes.
  DispatchHeap: 000007ff00053000(31000:14000) Size: 0x14000(81920)bytes.
  CacheEntryHeap: 000007ff00046000(9000:9000) 000007ff00b60000(10000:a000) Size: 0x13000(77824)bytes.
Total size: 0xa6a000(10919936)bytes
--------------------------------------
Jit code heap:
LoaderCodeHeap: 000007ff00ef0000(40000:d000) Size: 0xd000(53248)bytes.
HostCodeHeap: 000007ff00ec0000 Size: 0xc000(49152)bytes.
HostCodeHeap: 000007ff00e90000 Size: 0xe000(57344)bytes.
LoaderCodeHeap: 000007ff00e30000(40000:40000) Size: 0x40000(262144)bytes.
HostCodeHeap: 000007ff00d90000 Size: 0xf000(61440)bytes.
HostCodeHeap: 000007ff00d70000 Size: 0xf000(61440)bytes.
HostCodeHeap: 000007ff00d40000 Size: 0xf000(61440)bytes.
HostCodeHeap: 000007ff00ce0000 Size: 0xf000(61440)bytes.
HostCodeHeap: 000007ff00cd0000 Size: 0xf000(61440)bytes.
LoaderCodeHeap: 000007ff00c80000(40000:40000) Size: 0x40000(262144)bytes.
HostCodeHeap: 000007ff00c60000 Size: 0xb000(45056)bytes.
HostCodeHeap: 000007ff00c10000 Size: 0xf000(61440)bytes.
HostCodeHeap: 000007ff00ba0000 Size: 0xf000(61440)bytes.
LoaderCodeHeap: 000007ff00ab0000(40000:40000) Size: 0x40000(262144)bytes.
HostCodeHeap: 000007ff00a90000 Size: 0xf000(61440)bytes.
HostCodeHeap: 000007ff00a50000 Size: 0xf000(61440)bytes.
HostCodeHeap: 000007ff003b0000 Size: 0xf000(61440)bytes.
LoaderCodeHeap: 000007ff00240000(40000:40000) Size: 0x40000(262144)bytes.
Total size: 0x1c8000(1867776)bytes
--------------------------------------
Module Thunk heaps:
Module 000007feebbc1000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff000e2568: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff000e2020: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff00032e30: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007fee9eb1000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007feeb191000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007feeaf51000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff00038208: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff002075c0: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007fee9051000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007fee94d1000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007fee9381000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007fee9c71000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff002ea138: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff002edaf8: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007fee8801000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007fee7ad1000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007fee5551000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007feedcd1000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007feedbc1000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007fee5251000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff005e58a8: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff005ec7c8: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff005eeae8: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff00724518: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff0075b530: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff0075c920: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007fee63f1000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff00849de0: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff00877b60: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff009a1440: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff009a1d30: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff009e7d78: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff00db1fb0: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff00db9e30: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Total size: 0x0(0)bytes
--------------------------------------
Module Lookup Table heaps:
Module 000007feebbc1000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff000e2568: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff000e2020: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff00032e30: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007fee9eb1000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007feeb191000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007feeaf51000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff00038208: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff002075c0: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007fee9051000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007fee94d1000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007fee9381000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007fee9c71000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff002ea138: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff002edaf8: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007fee8801000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007fee7ad1000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007fee5551000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007feedcd1000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007feedbc1000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007fee5251000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff005e58a8: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff005ec7c8: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff005eeae8: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff00724518: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff0075b530: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff0075c920: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007fee63f1000: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff00849de0: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff00877b60: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff009a1440: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff009a1d30: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff009e7d78: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff00db1fb0: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Module 000007ff00db9e30: Size: 0x0(0)bytes.
Total size: 0x0(0)bytes
--------------------------------------
Total LoaderHeap size: 0xc77000(13070336)bytes
=======================================
The garbage collector data structures are not in a valid state for traversal.
It is either in the "plan phase," where objects are being moved around, or
we are at the initialization or shutdown of the gc heap. Commands related to 
displaying, finding or traversing objects as well as gc heap segments may not 
work properly. !dumpheap and !verifyheap may incorrectly complain of heap 
consistency errors.
Number of GC Heaps: 1
generation 0 starts at 0x00000003e1d5a588
generation 1 starts at 0x00000003e14a6e88
generation 2 starts at 0x0000000002a61000
ephemeral segment allocation context: (0x00000003e1d5a588, 0x00000003e1d5a5a0)
         segment            begin         allocated             size
0000000002a60000 0000000002a61000  0000000012a5fd90 0x000000000fffed90(268430736)
000000002b850000 000000002b851000  000000003b84ff10 0x000000000fffef10(268431120)
000000003b850000 000000003b851000  000000004b84fd38 0x000000000fffed38(268430648)
000000004b850000 000000004b851000  000000005b84f370 0x000000000fffe370(268428144)
000000005b850000 000000005b851000  000000006b84f7e8 0x000000000fffe7e8(268429288)
000000007fff0000 000000007fff1000  000000008ffeed20 0x000000000fffdd20(268426528)
0000000097ff0000 0000000097ff1000  00000000a7fef398 0x000000000fffe398(268428184)
00000000a7ff0000 00000000a7ff1000  00000000b7fef3a8 0x000000000fffe3a8(268428200)
00000000b7ff0000 00000000b7ff1000  00000000c7fef860 0x000000000fffe860(268429408)
00000000c7ff0000 00000000c7ff1000  00000000d7fefee0 0x000000000fffeee0(268431072)
00000000e3ff0000 00000000e3ff1000  00000000f3feff90 0x000000000fffef90(268431248)
00000000f3ff0000 00000000f3ff1000  0000000103fefe98 0x000000000fffee98(268431000)
0000000103ff0000 0000000103ff1000  0000000113feffb0 0x000000000fffefb0(268431280)
0000000113ff0000 0000000113ff1000  0000000123feffd8 0x000000000fffefd8(268431320)
0000000123ff0000 0000000123ff1000  0000000133fefda8 0x000000000fffeda8(268430760)
0000000133ff0000 0000000133ff1000  0000000143fefbd0 0x000000000fffebd0(268430288)
0000000143ff0000 0000000143ff1000  0000000153fef658 0x000000000fffe658(268428888)
0000000153ff0000 0000000153ff1000  0000000163feffa8 0x000000000fffefa8(268431272)
0000000163ff0000 0000000163ff1000  0000000173fef0e0 0x000000000fffe0e0(268427488)
0000000195800000 0000000195801000  00000001a57ffba8 0x000000000fffeba8(268430248)
00000001a5800000 00000001a5801000  00000001b57ffca8 0x000000000fffeca8(268430504)
00000001b5800000 00000001b5801000  00000001c57ffc88 0x000000000fffec88(268430472)
00000001c5800000 00000001c5801000  00000001d57ff448 0x000000000fffe448(268428360)
00000001d5800000 00000001d5801000  00000001e57fef50 0x000000000fffdf50(268427088)
00000001e5800000 00000001e5801000  00000001f57ff1a8 0x000000000fffe1a8(268427688)
00000001f5800000 00000001f5801000  00000002057fff08 0x000000000fffef08(268431112)
0000000205800000 0000000205801000  00000002157ff0c0 0x000000000fffe0c0(268427456)
0000000215800000 0000000215801000  00000002257feff0 0x000000000fffdff0(268427248)
0000000225800000 0000000225801000  00000002357ffa28 0x000000000fffea28(268429864)
0000000235800000 0000000235801000  00000002457ffd28 0x000000000fffed28(268430632)
0000000245800000 0000000245801000  00000002557ffd38 0x000000000fffed38(268430648)
0000000255800000 0000000255801000  00000002657ff440 0x000000000fffe440(268428352)
0000000265800000 0000000265801000  00000002757ff590 0x000000000fffe590(268428688)
0000000275800000 0000000275801000  00000002857ff3e0 0x000000000fffe3e0(268428256)
0000000285800000 0000000285801000  00000002957ffef8 0x000000000fffeef8(268431096)
0000000295800000 0000000295801000  00000002a57ffb88 0x000000000fffeb88(268430216)
00000002a5800000 00000002a5801000  00000002b57fefd8 0x000000000fffdfd8(268427224)
00000002d9800000 00000002d9801000  00000002e97ffcb8 0x000000000fffecb8(268430520)
00000002e9800000 00000002e9801000  00000002f97ff420 0x000000000fffe420(268428320)
00000002f9800000 00000002f9801000  00000003097ffd88 0x000000000fffed88(268430728)
0000000324810000 0000000324811000  000000033480fc88 0x000000000fffec88(268430472)
0000000374810000 0000000374811000  000000038480fd58 0x000000000fffed58(268430680)
0000000173ff0000 0000000173ff1000  0000000183fefc00 0x000000000fffec00(268430336)
0000000183ff0000 0000000183ff1000  0000000193fefe58 0x000000000fffee58(268430936)
0000000334810000 0000000334811000  000000034480f210 0x000000000fffe210(268427792)
0000000344810000 0000000344811000  000000035480ffe8 0x000000000fffefe8(268431336)
0000000354810000 0000000354811000  000000036480f1f8 0x000000000fffe1f8(268427768)
0000000364810000 0000000364811000  000000037480f388 0x000000000fffe388(268428168)
0000000384810000 0000000384811000  000000039480f198 0x000000000fffe198(268427672)
0000000394810000 0000000394811000  00000003a480fa50 0x000000000fffea50(268429904)
00000003a4810000 00000003a4811000  00000003b480f3c8 0x000000000fffe3c8(268428232)
00000003b4810000 00000003b4811000  00000003c480ed10 0x000000000fffdd10(268426512)
00000003c4810000 00000003c4811000  00000003d480f258 0x000000000fffe258(268427864)
00000003d4810000 00000003d4811000  00000003e235a5d8 0x000000000db495d8(229938648)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000000012a61000
         segment            begin         allocated             size
0000000012a60000 0000000012a61000  0000000017bb9bf0 0x0000000005158bf0(85298160)
00000002b5800000 00000002b5801000  00000002d5801020 0x0000000020000020(536870944)
Total Size       0x382c54048(15078867016)
------------------------------
GC Heap Size       0x382c54048(15078867016)



0:000> !address -summary

--- Usage Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
Free                                    217      7fc`3fb62000 (   7.985 Tb)           99.82%
                          733        3`b3e80000 (  14.811 Gb)  98.71%    0.18%
Image                                   950        0`0c5a9000 ( 197.660 Mb)   1.29%    0.00%
TEB                                      42        0`00054000 ( 336.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%
ActivationContextData                    11        0`00010000 (  64.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%
PEB                                       1        0`00001000 (   4.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%

--- Type Summary (for busy) ------ RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
MEM_PRIVATE                             621        3`ae855000 (  14.727 Gb)  98.15%    0.18%
MEM_IMAGE                              1068        0`0da22000 ( 218.133 Mb)   1.42%    0.00%
MEM_MAPPED                               48        0`04217000 (  66.090 Mb)   0.43%    0.00%

--- State Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
MEM_FREE                                217      7fc`3fb62000 (   7.985 Tb)           99.82%
MEM_COMMIT                             1493        3`b2ba3000 (  14.793 Gb)  98.59%    0.18%
MEM_RESERVE                             244        0`0d8eb000 ( 216.918 Mb)   1.41%    0.00%

--- Protect Summary (for commit) - RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
PAGE_READWRITE                          570        3`a1e76000 (  14.530 Gb)  96.84%    0.18%
PAGE_EXECUTE_READ                       113        0`0ad30000 ( 173.188 Mb)   1.13%    0.00%
PAGE_READONLY                           343        0`04137000 (  65.215 Mb)   0.42%    0.00%
PAGE_WRITECOPY                          199        0`0126e000 (  18.430 Mb)   0.12%    0.00%
PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE                  182        0`00a81000 (  10.504 Mb)   0.07%    0.00%
PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY                   43        0`00115000 (   1.082 Mb)   0.01%    0.00%
PAGE_READWRITE|PAGE_GUARD                42        0`000be000 ( 760.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%
PAGE_EXECUTE                              1        0`00004000 (  16.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%

--- Largest Region by Usage ----------- Base Address -------- Region Size ----------
Free                                      5`16fc6000      63d`e8c1a000 (   6.242 Tb)
                            2`b5800000        0`20022000 ( 512.133 Mb)
Image                                   7fe`e68ba000        0`01145000 (  17.270 Mb)
TEB                                     7ff`ffec8000        0`00002000 (   8.000 kb)
ActivationContextData                     0`00030000        0`00004000 (  16.000 kb)
PEB                                     7ff`fffd9000        0`00001000 (   4.000 kb)
```

Comment: !DumpHeap complains that `The garbage collector data structures are not in a valid state for traversal`. There is a high chance it shows incorrect result, because GC is currently working. If it would be live debugging, you would hit 'g' and then break into process again later when collection is finished. Since you cannot do that for dumps, your only chance is to try locate committed segments (using !address) and try to identify what kind of stuff was allocated there by looking at the memory (command `db` usually helps).

Comment: The output says, `GC Heap Size       0x382c54048(15078867016)`, so according to `!dumpheap` the managed heap is around 14 GB.

Comment: Thanks Seva, I'm guessing that you are correct. I received another dump which reproduces the issue, and this one was in a valid state so I could see all the objects in memory.